# Error occured while restoring NuGet packages: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package

I'm having a problem with NuGet since I clicked on **Clear All NuGet Cache(s)** button.

Since that time, when I close a project in Visual Studio and open up another project, I need to clear all NuGet cache and restore the packages over and over again!

I got this error often when I need to switch between projects

Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try these:

**1).** Restart VS.

**2).** Clear all NuGet cache by using command line in CMD, `nuget locals all -clear`(nuget.exe) or `dotnet nuget locals all --clear`(dotnet.exe). Refer to this doc: [Clearing local folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders). And then try to restore NuGet packages.

**3).** Delete project/VS cache files, such as `bin`, `obj` and the hidden `.vs` folder in your project folder. Go to `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_XXXXXXX` and delete `ComponentModelCache` folders in every 16.0_XXXXXX folders.

**4).** [Repair VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#how-to-repair) in Visual Studio Installer.

**Besides**, since we are not sure whether this issue is affected by the specific NuGet package(s), if you try to create one or two new simple projects, and add random NuGet packages into them and switch between this projects, will the same error appear?

Comment: Yes, even when a create a new project and in the first time the restore package works fine, but when I switch between project and come back to this new project, that error happens

Comment: So, do you have a local repository(package source) set? If yes, could you please try to disable it from NuGet Package Manager and enable only `nuget.org` and then try to test again.